# docker is pulling packages I don't instruct it to pull

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I'm building image with Docker using:

```
FROM python:3.6.5-alpine

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "main.py"]   # I've got set alias on Python == Python 3.6
```

requirements.txt:

```
alembic==1.0.9
cffi==1.12.3
bcrypt==3.1.6
blinker==1.4
Click==7.0
Faker==1.0.5
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==2.4.0
Flask-Moment==0.7.0
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-Testing==0.7.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
PyMySQL==0.9.3
SQLAlchemy==1.3.3
text-unidecode==1.2
Werkzeug==0.15.2
WTForms==2.2.1
```

However, when building:

```
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.6.5-alpine
---> 5be6d36f77ee
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> f9e7cc24d767
Step 3/6 : ADD . /app
---> 7d9d5bdcf5d6
Step 4/6 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
---> Running in b455df1a48e2
Collecting alembic==1.0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/42/8729e2491fa9b8eae160d1cbb429f61712bfc2d779816488c25cfdabf7b8/alembic-1.0.9.tar.gz (1.0MB)
Collecting bcrypt==3.1.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/3a/3d540b9f5ee8d92ce757eebacf167b9deedb8e30aedec69a2a072b2399bb/bcrypt-3.1.6.tar.gz (42kB)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cffi>=1.1 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cffi>=1.1
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

my requirements file doesn't contain package cffi at all and yet it's trying to pull it and fails. Initially, I figured it may be due to cache so I deleted all containers and images and building it from scratch but still getting the same error. As you can see for some mysterious reason it's also using pip instead of pip3.

But the question I'm asking is why is it pulling the package if it's not in requirements file ?

Comment: `bcrypt` depends on `cffi`: https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  Funny enough, I included latest version of cffi into requirements file (see update) and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pip will install dependencies if required. For example, if I run `pip install packageA`, but packageA depends on packageB and packageC, pip will install all 3 (or at least try to).

That is why you're seeing this behaviour.

Also pip3 doesn't refer to itself as pip3, so that message saying pip is outdated does not mean it's running the python2 version of pip. It should still be pip3.

Comment: Thank you for taking time explaining that. Do you by any chance why I get the same error even after adding the package above bcrypt ? Adding the package should fix the problem right ?